# Confusion with type inference and functional dependencies

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have the following multi-param typeclass with a functional dependency for types which are elements of vector spaces (vectors)

```
module Vec where

class Vec v k | v -> k where  -- v is an element of a vector space over k
    vZero :: v                -- The zero vector in v
    vAdd  :: v -> v -> v      -- Adds two vectors
    vSub  :: v -> v -> v      -- Subtracts two vectors
    vMul  :: v -> k -> v      -- Multiplies a vector by a number from k

infixl 6 |+|   -- Shortcut operator for accessing vAdd
(|+|) :: Vec v k => v -> v -> v
(|+|) = vAdd
```

Now I load the piece of code above into the `ghci` interpreter and ask it to show me the type of operator `|+|`:

```
*Vec> :t (|+|)
(|+|) :: Vec v k => v -> v -> v
```

By now, everything seems normal. But now I want to specify that all numbers are elements of a special vector spaces over themselves:

```
instance Num k => Vec k k where
    vZero = 0
    vAdd = (+)
    vSub = (-)
    vMul = (*)
```

And now a strange thing happens: `ghci` no longer shows the correct type for `|+|` (despite it being explicitly specified by me in the code above):

```
*Vec> :t (|+|)
(|+|) :: Num v => v -> v -> v
```

I suspect this strange behaviour to be linked with the `FunctionalDependencies` language extension which I am using, but I don't understand why `ghc` behaves this way. I can see myself adding a different instance `Vec v k` where `v` is **not** an instance of `Num` and thus such instance will not overlap with the existing one, thus preserving the functional dependency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have defined very general instance: `Vec v ...`.
Without overlapping instances there cannot be other ones.

E.g. adding

```
data V2 k = V2 k k
instance Num k => Vec (V2 k) k where
```

results into

```
Functional dependencies conflict between instance declarations:
  instance Num k => Vec k k -- Defined at v.hs:15:10
  instance Num k => Vec (V2 k) k -- Defined at v.hs:23:10
```

Actually overlapping instances doesn't help here either (this might be a GHC miss-feature?).

If you try to encode this using `TypeFamilies` you get similar error:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
module Vec where

class Vec v where  -- v is an element of a vector space over k
    type Elem v
    vZero :: v                 -- The zero vector in v
    vAdd  :: v -> v -> v       -- Adds two vectors
    vSub  :: v -> v -> v       -- Subtracts two vectors
    vMul  :: v -> Elem v -> v  -- Multiplies a vector by a number from k

infixl 6 |+|   -- Shortcut operator for accessing vAdd
(|+|) :: Vec v k => v -> v -> v
(|+|) = vAdd

data V2 k = V2 k k

instance Num k => Vec (V2 k) where
    type Elem (V2 k) = k
    -- implementation omitted

instance Num k => Vec k where
    type Elem k = k
    vZero = 0
    vAdd = (+)
    vSub = (-)
    vMul = (*)
```

errors with:

```
Conflicting family instance declarations:
  Elem (V2 k) -- Defined at v.hs:20:10
  Elem k -- Defined at v.hs:23:10
```

---

Solution would be to define helper functions and write instance definitions "by hand":

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, FunctionalDependencies #-}
module Vec where

class Vec v k | v -> k where  -- v is an element of a vector space over k
    vZero :: v                -- The zero vector in v
    vAdd  :: v -> v -> v      -- Adds two vectors
    vSub  :: v -> v -> v      -- Subtracts two vectors
    vMul  :: v -> k -> v      -- Multiplies a vector by a number from k

infixl 6 |+|   -- Shortcut operator for accessing vAdd
(|+|) :: Vec v k => v -> v -> v
(|+|) = vAdd

-- The definitions are so short, that it's not worth even givin them names
numVZero :: Num k => k
numVZero = 0

instance Vec Int Int where
    vZero = 0
    vAdd = (+)
    vSub = (-)
    vMul = (*)

data V2 k = V2 k k
instance Num k => Vec (V2 k) k where
    vZero = V2 0 0
    vAdd (V2 a b) (V2 c d) = V2 (a + c) (b + d)
    vSub (V2 a b) (V2 c d) = V2 (a - c) (b - d)
    vMul (V2 a b) k        = V2 (a * k) (b * k)
```

Then:

```
λ *Vec > :t (|+|)
(|+|) :: Vec v k => v -> v -> v
```

---

Or as `Num v => Vec v v` is probably going to be quite common you can use `DefaultSignatures`
to reduce boilerplate of instance declaration:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, FlexibleInstances, FunctionalDependencies, DefaultSignatures #-}
module Vec where

class Vec v k | v -> k where  -- v is an element of a vector space over k
    vZero :: v                -- The zero vector in v
    default vZero :: (Num v, v ~ k) => v
    vZero = 0

    vAdd  :: v -> v -> v      -- Adds two vectors
    default vAdd :: (Num v, v ~ k) => v -> v -> v
    vAdd = (+)

    vSub  :: v -> v -> v      -- Subtracts two vectors
    default vSub :: (Num v, v ~ k) => v -> v -> v
    vSub = (-)

    vMul  :: v -> k -> v      -- Multiplies a vector by a number from k
    default vMul :: (Num v, v ~ k) => v -> k -> v
    vMul = (*)

infixl 6 |+|   -- Shortcut operator for accessing vAdd
(|+|) :: Vec v k => v -> v -> v
(|+|) = vAdd

instance Vec Int Int
instance Vec Integer Integer
instance Vec Float Float
instance Vec Double Double

data V2 k = V2 k k
instance Num k => Vec (V2 k) k where
    vZero = V2 0 0
    vAdd (V2 a b) (V2 c d) = V2 (a + c) (b + d)
    vSub (V2 a b) (V2 c d) = V2 (a - c) (b - d)
    vMul (V2 a b) k        = V2 (a * k) (b * k)
```

Comment: You can save a bit of boilerplate by using [DefaultSignatures](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#class-default-signatures) and defining the default types as, e.g., `default vAdd :: (Num k, v ~ k) => k -> k -> k; vAdd = (+)`. Then you can simply write `instance Vec Int Int; instance Vec Float Float; instance Vec Integer Integer` etc, omitting the body of the instance.

Comment: I wonder if it might pay to use a simple newtype mask. `newtype Self a = Self a` represents the vector field perspective of a numeric type, so then you can have `instance Num a => Vec (Self a) a where ...`.